# MySQL remote connection from UWP with socket error but TCP connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sockets

I have a small C# app (VS 2017, UWP) on a developer machine which should feed a MySQL-database on another machine.

Using the MySQL-shell I can connect, but the app cannot (access to one socket denied because of socket permissions for this socket).

The app works fine with the database on the developer machine (localhost).
After hours of searching the web I understand that remote access happens either through socket or TCP; also, that socket is not really a thing in Windows.

However in the my.ini-file there are 2 places with socket (#socket =0.0 and #socket=MySQL, which I uncommented with error as before).

I have a TCP connection, so why is there a socket error? Named pipe seems to be a Windows-equivalent to socket somehow, but limited to local connection and again as an alternative to TCP as I understand it.

Strange is that on the workbench server status the path to the configuration file shows"...MySQL Server 5.5\ my.ini" although the Server is 5.7, which is the real folder name too. One would think the config file can't be found, but why is the connection working when using the shell? Can the shell make connection without the my.ini? Could that be the fault?

I have re-installed MySQL because I thought there was a corrupted installation, but same result. (On the developer machine the path is correct.

Would be very happy if someone could help!

Comment: You can only have one connection on a PC with the same destination IP and Port.  You may be opening the same conneciton more than once.  There is no reason that the MySQL-shell can connect and your c# application cannot from the same PC.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! So it may have happened like this: I tried the shell-connection and soon afterwards from the app, but the shell-connection was still on... I was observing the connection status on the workbench, but as I am new to MySQL and an amateur anyway, I did not get everything what happens there.

Comment: You can check the status of a connection from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give all the tpc connectons.

Answer (score 0):

A unix socket is for communication between process on the same host. On a local machine you can use a socket or TCP. If you want a remote connection then it's TCP.

Comment: Ok, but why is there a socket permission error when it is a TCP connection and a windows machine?